# Get records that look like a string with several mixed words

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, string-matching

**Database type**: MySql

Supposing there are two rows like this in my **table**:

> **[1.]** *"Peter **went to the** park yesterday"*
>  **[2.]** *"Peter is going the park
>   tomorrow"*

...and assuming I have this as pattern string:

> *"Mark **went to the** cinema **yesterday**"*

...How could I make a query to get the first record?
There could be many other cases where the first record would be the one I am looking for:

> *-"Leonard **went to the** Library last night"*
>   *-"Jake **went to** London last year"*

...and so on.

---

**Note**: I am not showing the table structure because the real issue is the condition I have to look for. However, we could suppose the table is called **table**, and there are two fields (*id* and *string*)

**Edit**: I know there are [FULLTEXT index in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) which may help to get this work. I have also read they [do not work with **innoDB** tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html) (which I am working with). *(If it is just impossible, I could redesign my DB to make this table be MyISAM)*

**Edit**: As eggyal says in the first comment to this question, "v5.6" supports **innoDB** tables too.

**Edit**: Another example would be:

> **[1.]** The heaven **looks blue today**
>   **[2.]** The fire looks red today

And I want to get the first record by assuming:

> The ocean **looks blue today**

...as pattern string.

(In this case, the second record would be a match too, with less relevance than the first one, since it contains **looks *$* today**)

Comment: From your most recent edit, it sounds as though fulltext search is exactly what you're after: e.g. `WHERE MATCH(myColumn) AGAINST ('Mark went to the cinema yesterday') > 0 ORDER BY MATCH(myColumn) AGAINST ('Mark went to the cinema yesterday') DESC`.

Comment: Yes, a relevance score `>0` means that there is at least *some* relevance.  `FULLTEXT` search is case insensitive.  More/less relevance will come from more/less matches between the pattern and the field.

Comment: All right, working nice. Thanks a lot (now I can vote you up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `like` in the query. See following examples:

```
mysql> select * from statements;
+----------------------------------+
| sentence                         |
+----------------------------------+
| Peter went to the park yesterday |
| Mark went to the cinema          |
| Peter is going the park tomorrow |
| Mark went to the park yesterday  |
| Mark went to the park tommorow   |
+----------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from statements where sentence like '% went to the park yesterday';
+----------------------------------+
| sentence                         |
+----------------------------------+
| Peter went to the park yesterday |
| Mark went to the park yesterday  |
+----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from statements where sentence like '% went to the park %';
+----------------------------------+
| sentence                         |
+----------------------------------+
| Peter went to the park yesterday |
| Mark went to the park yesterday  |
| Mark went to the park tommorow   |
+----------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The third example should exactly give what Mark ased for. +1